# Selecting the transect lines which touches the divide of a polygon from the river line

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-processing, watershed

I have a polygon and transect lines which passes inside the polygon.
[image]

Here I want to select the lines which touch the drainage and divide. The transect lines split at the river intersection.

[image]

Since all the transect lines lies inside the polygon the intersection selection selects most of the unwanted features. Is there any tool that I can use to automatically perform to get similar results?

Comment: I would like to think of it as the line that touches the river and boundary of a watershed. Considering longest will give me error while applying this elsewhere.

Comment: In the second figure, I have selected the lines which I needed(yellow). I am not considering the length of the line. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create this sort of thing, then there is a way. I am assuming you have already broken the transects at the river. Looks like you have.

[image]

1. Convert the watershed polygon to a line. This creates a polyline *boundary*. You can use **Vector - Geometry - Polygons to Lines**
2. **Vector - Geoprocessing Tools - Buffer** the boundary by a *small amount* so that the transects definitely cross the boundary. This creates a *polygon* watershed boundary. If you are using lat/long , a 'small amount is about 0.001 degrees or so. Zooming in, you can see that the transect terminates in the buffer.

   [image]
3. Make sure there is a *unique field* (eg integer field called "MY_ID") in the *buffered watershed boundary* (important :-). If you only have one watershed boundary, you can set MY_ID=0 in the attribute table.
4. Select your transects layer (which has already been broken at the river)
5. Go to **Vector - Data Management Tools - Join Attributes by Location** and bring up the dialog:

   [image]

- The base layer contains the transects.
- The join layer has the buffered watershed boundary.
- select **intersection** for the join

==> execute!

5. A layer called **Joined Layer** is created. Open its *Attribute Table*. You can see that there is a new attribute field based on the MY_ID field you created in the buffered watershed boundary polygon layer. Half of the values have information. Half are NULL. You can :

- Style this new layer to highlight the non_NULL joined transects
- set it via layer query.
- delete the others.